# keycloak - authentication with header enrichment

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-spi

I am working on a solution in which user will be authenticated using header (Think of Mobile Network Login)

Here is the use case:

- User launch the mobile app
- Validation failed, so launch the keycloak login page by sending header(ex: MSISDN)
- If the authentication flow detects, header MSISDN, validate the user against keycloak database and return the token as part of PKCE Code Flow Authentication
- If no header found, prompt for UserName password page

I am thinking of using the browser flow with alternate flow as Conditional Header. I am thinking in right direction? Please provide some light on this.